# A Command Line To-Do List (CLI) application written in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, to-do-list

I wrote this code for myself so I can manage my personal to-do list easier. Considering, I spend most of my time in the terminal, it made sense.

I have worked on the project as a way of practising my JS skills. The application works as expected.

I would like feedback on how I can improve the code as a whole. But there are two areas id like some focused help on:

1. I am not sure if the way I handled the `.then()` is the best way.
2. Enquirer takes an array. But when it gives back the array in the answer the actionList becomes an array of objects with lots of information about the prompt. So, I created a new array and pushed that to the file with the same name. I do not believe that was the best way. But it's the best I can do right now.

Thanks

### The code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node
//---------------- Start of Vanilla Package Imports -------------- //
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
//---------------- End of Vanilla Package Imports -------------- //
//
//---------------- Start of NPM Package Imports -------------- //
const chalk = require('chalk');
const cliBoxes = require('cli-boxes');
const logSymbols = require('log-symbols');
const { Select } = require('enquirer');
//---------------- End of NPM Package Imports -------------- //
//
//---------------- Start of Data Imports -------------- //
let { actionList } = require('./.todo.json');
const { name, version, tagline } = require('./utils/welcome');
//---------------- End of Data Imports -------------- //
//
//---------------- Start of Formating Terminal Variables -------------- //
const headerColor = chalk.hex('#fff').bgHex('.3399cc').bold;
const whiteBG = chalk.bgWhite.black.bold;
//---------------- End of Formating Terminal Variables -------------- //

console.clear();
const prompt = new Select({
    name: 'remove',
    message: chalk
        .hex('#3399cc')
        .bold(
            "Do you want to remove an action from your to-do list? \n   Select an action or quit with 'Do Nothing'" +
                '\n'
        ),
    choices: actionList,
});

prompt.run().then((answer) => {
    if (answer !== 'Do Nothing') {
        // prompt.state.index is the index value for the choice selected
        responseIndex = prompt.state.index;
        process.stdout.write('\n');
        console.log(`You removed to do list item: ` + chalk.green(answer));
        //enquirer changes the array to an array of objects. I needed to recreate the simple array of actions
        let newList = [];
        //push all actions to new array
        for (const action of actionList) {
            // newList.push()
            newList.push(action.name);
        }
        //remove selected item
        newList.splice(responseIndex, 1);
        //make new array equal old array. data import with "let". value not immutable.
        actionList = newList;
        //write over old list with new list to save the removed action
        fs.writeFileSync(
            path.join(__dirname, './.todo.json'),
            JSON.stringify({ actionList }, null, 4)
        );
    } else {
        //if "Do Nothing" is selected
        process.stdout.write('\n');
        console.log(
            logSymbols.info,
            chalk.blue(`The action list was not modified`)
        );
        process.exit();
    }
});
```

Comment: It's usually easier for reviewers if you don't remove the imports before posting your code.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the firstback friend. I will add them in